# Regularity of Cauchy-like integral

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, analytic-continuation

I'm trying to understand whether a certain integral representation is holomorphic. Specifically, let's assume that $f$ belongs to the Schwartz space $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$, and consider a function $g(z)$ represented in the following way:

\begin{align*} g(z) = \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{f(y)}{z- y} dy \end{align*}

It is my understanding that this function should be holomorphic when $\textrm{Im z} > 0$ and $\textrm{Im z} < 0$. This is because the integrand $\frac{f(y)}{z- y}$ is holomorphic in those regions. This can be shown as follows:

\begin{align*} \partial_{\bar z} \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{f(y)}{z- y} dy = \int_{\mathbb R} \partial_{\bar z} \frac{f(y)}{z- y} dy = 0 \end{align*}

So it seems that the function is indeed holomorphic. However, I'm not entirely sure of this reasoning. Is there anything wrong with it, or is there something else I should consider?

Any help and explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your proof, you never invoked anything special about the domain of $z$ for the calculation. Why is $\operatorname{Im} z > 0 $ a valid domain of holomorphicity for example? Is differentiation allowed if we deviate from these domains?

Comment: Isn't it delicate to define the integral when z lies on the real axis?